# Is there any way to add database proxy for specific database(Hana DB) in aws RDS Proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-serverless

Am trying to create a proxy for my hana db which will be called from a lamda function to write to hana db.

I see MySQL and Postgres. is this only 2 supported.

Am new to Aws so could someone tell me how can this be achieved ?

[image: Here is the proxy screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AWS RDS proxy only currently supports MySQL and PostgreSQL database engines. There is no way around this.